# How to prevent execution of main Python code when importing a function

Tags: python, python-import

Consider the two following files:

test.py:

```
import sys

def testfunction(string):
    print(string)

sys.exit(0)
```

test2.py:

```
from test import testfunction

testfunction("string")
```

I would expect the import of testfunction not to execute statements outside of that function, e.g., sys.exit(0). Why is this happening, and how can I prevent it?

Comment: besides the answers given, that are right, you can also arrange all your functions as methods of some outer class. The class code is executed, but not the def inner code blocks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quite simply:

```
# test.py
import sys

def testfunction(string):
    print(string)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    sys.exit(0)
```

The magic variable `__name__` is set either to the module name (when the file is imported as a module) or to `"__main__"` when it's executed as a script.

Comment: Thanks. If one intends to import a function from a source file, there is no way in the example above to avoid the sys.exit() call except by modifying that source file to include this `__name__` check?

Comment: well you could wrap the import in a try/except block and catch the SystemExit exception. But fixing the problem at the source (and contributing it back if it's oss) would probably be better.

Comment: Err well, no it actually won't work :-/

Answer (score 0):

Put everything you don't want to be executed under the condition

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    ...
    sys.exit(0)
```